# Why type assertion that surely fails is not a syntax error?

Tags: go

I was going through [this](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15) tour of go.

Initially i is declared an interface with type string.
`var i interface{} = "hello"`

But when we do

`f = i.(float64) // panic`

My question is, why isn't this caught during compile time in golang.
C++ generics catch this during compile time, unlike go which decides to do it at runtime.

The "type" information for `i` exists during compilation.
This kind of issue would be something that would make it easier (from a golang programmer's perspective) to catch during compilation than runtime.

edit: Eduardo Thales suggested that generics were included later in golang. I was under the assumption that the underlying mechanism of interfaces is generics. apparently not. Thanks Eduardo

Comment: `float64` implements `interface{}`, that's why `i.(float64)` is valid, semantically.

Comment: This cannot be done during compile time in general. Note that this is not an "exception".

Comment: "valid, semantically": How can something be valid semantically and yet cause syntax issues.
Also, it is not like this can't be done.
C++ uses generics to detect this and cause compilation failures in case the underlying type doesn't match.

Comment: Golang interfaces have nothing to do with C++ generics. It's a runtime check, it will only fail at runtime.

Comment: That is my question. Why golang decides to do it at runtime than compile time?
I know it has nothing to do with C++ generics. I was just trying to say a better language design would have been to move this check to compilation (unless I am missing something)

Comment: *"and yet cause syntax issues"* -- a runtime `panic` can hardly be a syntax issue.

Comment: I would rephrase your question them, because it just sounds like you want to know how interfaces work. You want to know why Golang didn't had generics (it has generics since 1.18) and instead prefers using interfaces checked at runtime. It's a tradeoff, you don't just "add generics" to the language, it can greatly complicate the type system and increase compile times, for example.

Comment: You can read the rationale for Golang generics here: https://go.dev/doc/faq#generics It also includes an explanation of why Golang didn't have generics from the start: it's a tradeoff!

Comment: @DeepanshuLulla note that why-this-and-not-that-design type of questions are generally considered off-topic for SO.

Comment: Reframed the question. I was under the assumption that the underlying body of an interface is generics. Was Mostly looking for context on why things were implemented a certain way.

Comment: No, interfaces are not generics. What you are doing is a runtime “type assertion”, which by definition is checked at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The [language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) explicitly says that false type assertions cause a run-time panic. See:

> If the type assertion is false, a run-time panic occurs.

Also, there's nothing in the language that says that you can't make a program that will unambiguously panic. For example, this is a valid program that will compile without error:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Don't panic!")
    panic(1)
}
```

Comment: My question wasn't why does it panic. My question is why it decides to panic. Instead of throwing out an error at compile time. this is something that can be cheaper to check during compilation.

Comment: Asking about why the language is designed the way that it is is generally off topic on this site, unfortunately.

Comment: In what way would it be cheaper? The run-time assertion is already dirt simple in terms of design, implementation and execution (just checking equality of a pointer).

Comment: Cheaper in the sense. It will be detected before program even runs.

Comment: It cannot be detected before execution in general, so no gain here.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up generics and variable types.
Take this as an example:

```golang
items := []string{"item1", "item2"}
fmt.Println(slices.Contains(items, "item1"))
```

The variable type is `slice`. The generic part is `string`, which is regarded in `slices.Contains`.
So, `fmt.Println(slices.Contains(items, 1))` would cause a compile time error because the generic type `string` doesn't match the generic type `int`.

(NB: `slice` is not the best representative of a typical generic in Go because usually they look different, but it's the easiest one to grasp the concept.)

@mkopriva has already answered why your code doesn't cause a compile error: `float64` is a valid subtype of `interface{}`.
If it wasn't, you'ld get a compile time error here as well, e.g. as in

```golang
var i string = "hello"
f := i.(float64) // compile time error
```

Generics don't even exist here, though, and neither they did in your example.